# SSRS - Report Builder 2016 not downloading on client's browser

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0, reportbuilder, ssrs-2017

I am unable to download report builder on client's browser. Its showing following error screen (right bottom) and error log.[image]

SQL Server 2017 Standard Edition installed on Azure VM. SQL Server 2016 Report Builder also installed on Azure VM. Report display working perfectly with SSRS Report URL. I have checked on both link http & https its giving same error. Also i have implemented Microsoft.Samples.ReportingServices.AnonymousSecurity. I am using google chrome browser at client where i have installed "ClickOnce for Google Chrome".

Please help if anyone have any idea.

Thanks

Comment: Does your client have .NET Framework 4.5 installed?  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53613

Comment: Yes its installed